# Update and Select count in one query in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to now if it is possible to create one Hibernate Query which counts in a table and updates the result into a parent table.

We have in our Spring Boot Backend multiple times the case, that we select count(x) on a table and the result is persisted to the parent entitiy with an update statement. So my question is, is something like that possible:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Post post SET post.commentsCount = (SELECT (count(comment) FROM Comments comment WHERE comment.post = :post)) WHERE post = :post")
void updateCommentCount(@Param("post")Post post);
```

With correct brackets it works.. :) Thanks to @Sana.

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Query("UPDATE Post post SET post.commentsCount = (SELECT count(comment) FROM Comments comment WHERE comment.post = :post) WHERE post = :post")
void updateCommentCounttest(@Param("post")Post post);
```

Comment: I think with native postgreSQL it is possible, but since native queries are bad for maintenance a hibernate solution would be wonderful.

Comment: Does this one not work?

Comment: You can try `JPQL`or `HQL` ou `Criteria` or `QueryDSL` Query.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer no.

Comment: @Zorglube i will have a look at it thanks.

Comment: It is possible. But you need to put the brackets correctly

Comment: Take a look at hibernate `@Formula`